# TensorFlow installation error on Mac

Tags: python, macos, tensorflow

I want to use TensorFlow on my Mac with PyCharm, but when I use:

```
pip install https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/tensorflow-0.5.0-py2-none-any.whl
```

it gives an error:

```
    Exception:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/urAD_Jeff/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 211, in main
        status = self.run(options, args)
.
.
.
      File "/Users/urAD_Jeff/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/adapters.py", line 431, in send
        raise SSLError(e, request=request)
    SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590)
```

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it to install by running the following for a virtualenv setup recommended by the [documentation](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/get_started/os_setup.md#user-content-virtualenv-based-installation-virtualenv_install)

#### Install python

```
brew install python
```

#### Install tools

```
# On Mac:
$ sudo easy_install pip  # If pip is not already installed
$ sudo pip install --upgrade virtualenv
```

#### Setup virtualenv in ~/tensorflow directory

```
$ virtualenv --system-site-packages ~/tensorflow
$ cd ~/tensorflow
```

#### Activate virtualenv

```
$ source bin/activate  # If using bash
$ source bin/activate.csh  # If using csh
(tensorflow)$  # Your prompt should change
```

#### Install tensorflow (this is where I got the SSL error)

Download tensorflow from [google](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow#user-content-mac-os-x) getting the latest version using curl

```
curl -O https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/tensorflow-0.5.0-py2-none-any.whl
```

Install the package you downloaded

```
pip install tensorflow-0.5.0-py2-none-any.whl
```

You should be able to type `python` and try out tensorflow in a python terminal

Answer (score 0):

Another common issue in Mac while installing Tensor flow is Protobuf version.

Please make sure you have protobuf 3.0.0a3 or above.

Thanks to [Github Issue on Tensorflow](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/11#issuecomment-155174905) To install using homebrew

```
brew install --devel protobuf
```

To verify, please run

```
pip show numpy protobuf
```