# TensorFlow installation results in ImportError: No module named tensorflow

Tags: python, macos, tensorflow

I'm trying to get `TensorFlow` to work on my Mac (OSX El Capitan 10.11.2). I tried the `pip install` from the [setup guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/get_started/os_setup.html#download-and-setup) and also followed the instructions in [the accepted answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33730259/tensorflow-installation-error-on-mac).

In both cases I am able to successfully activate the `virtualenv` and my prompt changes to `tensorflow.` `Python` works fine, I'm able to do simple computations on the `command line`. But when I try to import tensorflow:

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

I repeatedly get this error:

```
ImportError: No module named tensorflow
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you check if the `lib/python2.x/site-packages/tensorflow` directory is present in your virtualenv dir?

Comment: It's not. What happened?

Comment: It means you have not installed tensorflow in the virtualenv, maybe you installed it in the system environment.

Comment: you have to run `pip install tensorflow-0.5.0-py2-none-any.whl` after you have activated virtualenv.

Comment: I tried from inside the tensorflow (virtualenv) directory and got an error. Not sure it's fatal but anyway there is still no tensorflow directory in the location. The error: Detected a distutils installed project ('numpy') which we cannot uninstall. The metadata provided by distutils does not contain a list of files which have been installed, so pip does not know which files to uninstall.

Comment: Do you still get this error message if you do `source bin/activate; pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.6.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl` from inside your virtualenv directory?

Comment: When I try the pip install I get tensorflow-0.6.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform. My OS is Mac El Capitain. I tried changing the "linux" strings into "osx" but I get the same error.

Comment: Ah, my apologies. What about if you try `source bin/activate; pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/tensorflow-0.6.0-py2-none-any.whl` from inside your virtualenv directory?

Comment: I'm getting this error: "Detected a distutils installed project ('numpy') which we cannot uninstall. The metadata provided by distutils does not contain a list of files which have been installed, so pip does not know which files to uninstall." I'm not sure if it's related but now there's a google directory inside  python2.7/site-packages -- but still no tensorflow directory.

Answer (score 1):

I had the issue reported in the original question.  Python worked fine, I followed the installation steps on the Tensforflow website, and got "No module named tensorflow."

Re-installing python via brew, and re-installing pip as a result, fixed it.  I didn't need to uninstall anything, just the line below along with the normal pip install from the tensorflow installation document afterwards:

```
brew install python
```